# Proper syntax for SolidColorBrush to set the specified color in C++ Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I created an ellipse element in my XAML in Visual C++ 2017 like this:

```
 <Ellipse x:Name="myEllipse1" Width="300" Height="150" Fill="DarkGreen" />
```

(I could not enter the beginning 'greater than sign' and at the end of the statement in herein.)

Clicking a button I want change the color of the ellipse. In MainPage.xaml.cpp* in my `InputButton_Click` using this statement

```
myEllipse->Fill = ref new SolidColorBrush();
```

I managed to change the color of the ellipse to the base color (which looks like the ellipse disappeared from the form), so far so good. However, I feel stupid to ask this, but how I am supposed to initialize a new instance SolidColorBrush properly WITH THE SPECIFIED COLOR (I can initialize one WITH NO COLOR)?
I feel I tried each and every imaginable syntax (including every possible syntax from MSDN reference), which always resulted in syntax error. What I am doing wrong here?

How I am to set the color for the brush in the code so that the color of the ellipse (or any other object) in the XAML form changes?
I am using Visual Studio C++ 2017.

Comment: Use the Code button in the editor to format the code, then you can use the <>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a Color for the `SolidColorBrush`.  There are many ways to do that, one way is via the constructor.  You are using the parameterless constructor which:

*Initializes a new instance of the SolidColorBrush class with no color.*

You want the other constructor.

*Initializes a new instance of the SolidColorBrush class with the specified 
Color:*

**Parameters**: color: The color to apply to the brush.

Here's an example.
You didn't specify if your project is WPF or UWP, the namespaces are different for the Colors class.

```
// UWP
myEllipse1->Fill = ref new SolidColorBrush(Windows::UI::Colors::Green);

// WPF
myEllipse1->Fill = ref new SolidColorBrush(System::Windows::Media::Colors::Green);
```

[MSDN - SolidColorBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_SolidColorBrush__ctor)